# Dojo loading unnecessary files (shape.js & path.js)

Tags: dojo, custom-build

I am using customized Dojo library. When I load my client application, Dojo load the below two files after loading the "dojox/gfx/svg.js" file.
1. dojox/gfx/shape.js 
2. dojox/gfx/path.js

Even though I have included these two files in to my Dojo Custom build, still these two files are always loading in to my client application.

I know the file "dojox/gfx/svg.js" will be load at run time based on the browser type, but why shape.js and path.js files are loading always at run time ?

Comment: double check that they are actually included in your custom build. do you see the dojo.provide(...) statements for path.js and shape.js?